# Import and wildcard interaction

Tags: import

I recently came across this behaviour of `Import`:

```
Export["new file.dat", {123,456,789}];
Import["new file.dat"]
Import["new*file.dat"]
```

The resulting `Import` has an additional level of braces if a wildcard is present in the `Import` instruction:

```
{{123}, {456}, {789}}
{{{123}, {456}, {789}}}
```

Although surprising, I'm guessing that the wildcard changes the heuristics `Import` uses to guess the format it's reading in.
My question is, can an option be given to `Import` so that it produces the same output for both the wildcard and exact file specification? Preferably two options can be found to consistently switch between the two output.

I've tried specifying `"Table"` or `"Data"` formats to `Import` but the result stays different. Additionally, maybe someone knows how to find out which format `Import` chooses when no option is specified. I know the result can be post-processed to be consistent, but I think that giving instructions to `Import` would allow more flexibility in entering the file name.

This is on *Mathematica* 11.3 for Linux.

Comment: By the way, the difference also exists if the written data is a string. No wildcard gives a naked string and wildcard gives a string in a list.

Comment: If that helps, I can reproduce what you see on Mathematica 11 for MacOs

Comment: The issue is not the guessing of the format. The issue is that since your file name is a pattern, it could match multiple file names, so `Import` returns a list of all matches it found (1 in your case). Not returning a list would be more inconsistent, because the same file name specification would then give differently structured results depending on the amount of files it found

Comment: @Mathe172 Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @Mathe172 That makes a lot of sense to me now that I've tested it out. Care to expand it into an answer? I can write it up if not. In this case it seems to me that there's no getting around processing the `Import` output after the fact.

Comment: @Szabolcs good question - I could have sworn that I've seen this somewhere in the docs, but I didn't find anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Putting my comment into an answer, as requested.

There seems to be an undocumented feature of [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) regarding wildcard support (if someone finds a reference, please leave a comment):

If the file name contains wildcards (string patterns do not seem to work), `Import` effectively maps over the result of `FileNames`, giving a list of results:

```
SetDirectory@CreateDirectory[];

Export["test1.txt", 1];
Export["test2.txt", 2];

Import["test1.txt"]
Import["test*.txt"]
(* "1" *)
(* {"1", "2"} *)
```

This explains what is happening in the question:

```
Import["*test1.txt"]
(* {"1"} *)
```

Even though there is only one file matched, `Import` still returns a list of all files found.

### Workaround

The following should provide a robust workaround in case this behavior is undesired and it is clear that the wildcard pattern will always match exactly one file:

```
Import@First@FileNames["*test1.txt"]
(* "1" *)
```